# The command "npm install" exited with code 9009 when creating a Docker Image

Tags: reactjs, docker, .net-core

When I try to create a Docker image from docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["project/project.csproj", "project/"]
RUN dotnet restore "project/project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/project"
RUN dotnet build "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]
```

I have this issue:

> The command "npm install" exited with code 9009.

I pasted `From node 10-alpine` but it's not working.

Comment: did you manage to solve it? I face the same problem. Reinstalling node didn't fix the issue